# Does surrounding try/catch break the forloop?

Tags: java, for-loop, try-catch

In the code below I was wondering if an exception was thrown in the for loop and the error message was added to the JSON object in the catch block, will the program return to the next iteration of the for loop after the exception was thrown? Or will it break the for loop and return the object?

```
JSONOBject obj = new JSONObject();
try
{
    for(i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
        //do things in here that may throw an exception
        obj.put("message","did not throw exception");
    }
{
catch(Exception e)
{
    obj.put("message",e.getMessage());
}
return obj;
```

Comment: Once you are in the catch block you can't go back to the try block

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An exception will terminate the method, because after the catch block the next statement is `return`.

If you want to continue the loop, put the entire try/catch inside the loop, as in:

```
for (.... whatever ...)
{
    try
    {
        something
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        obj.put("message",e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

In this case the loop will execute all specified iterations, and each exception caught will add a new message to `obj`.

Answer (score 1):

In a try block as soon as an error is thrown execution in that block stops and control jumps over to the catch block. Therefore in your case the rest of the for loop is not executed.

You can move the try catch into the for loop if you wish to continue through the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

No - the loop will be exited from the point when the exception is thrown - after catch block is done with.